# Loading Matlab sparse matrix using Python Pytables

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I originally asked a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403144/loading-matlab-sparse-matrix-saved-with-v7-3-hdf5-into-python-and-operating-o), but didn't really seem to get anywhere. Perhaps if I rephrase part of it more specifically it might help....

I have files stored using Matlab's sparse format (HDF5, csc I
believe), and I'm trying to use Pytables to operate on them directly,
but haven't succeeded yet. Using h5py I can do the following:

```
# Method 1: uses h5py (WORKS)
f1 = h5py.File(fname)
data = f1['M']['data']
ir = f1['M']['ir']
jc = f1['M']['jc']
M = scipy.sparse.csc_matrix((data, ir, jc))
```

but if I try to do the equivalent in Pytables:

```
# Method 2: uses pyTables (DOESN'T WORK)
f2 = tables.openFile(fname)
data = f2.root.M.data
ir = f2.root.M.ir
jc = f2.root.M.jc
M = scipy.sparse.csc_matrix( (data,ir,jc) )
```

this fails (after a long wait) with the error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/tdiethe/BMJ/<ipython console> in <module>()

/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.pyc in __init__(self, arg1, shape, dtype, copy, dims, nzmax)
    56                     self.indices = np.array(indices, copy=copy)
    57                     self.indptr  = np.array(indptr, copy=copy)
---> 58                     self.data    = np.array(data, copy=copy, dtype=getdtype(dtype, data))
    59                 else:
    60                     raise ValueError, "unrecognized %s_matrix constructor usage" %\

/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/sputils.pyc in getdtype(dtype, a, default)
    69                 canCast = False
    70             else:
---> 71                 raise TypeError, "could not interpret data type"
    72     else:
    73         newdtype = np.dtype(dtype)

TypeError: could not interpret data type
```

Looking at `f2`:

```
In [63]: f2.root.M.data
Out[63]: 
/M/data (CArray(4753606,), zlib(3)) ''
  atom := Float64Atom(shape=(), dflt=0.0)
  maindim := 0
  flavor := 'numpy'
  byteorder := 'little'
  chunkshape := (8181,)

In [64]: f2.root.M.ir
Out[64]: 
/M/ir (CArray(4753606,), zlib(3)) ''
  atom := UInt64Atom(shape=(), dflt=0)
  maindim := 0
  flavor := 'numpy'
  byteorder := 'little'
  chunkshape := (8181,)

In [65]: f2.root.M.jc
Out[65]: 
/M/jc (CArray(133339,), zlib(3)) ''
  atom := UInt64Atom(shape=(), dflt=0)
  maindim := 0
  flavor := 'numpy'
  byteorder := 'little'
  chunkshape := (7843,)
```

I have two questions:

- how do I load this file in using pytables
- do I need to perform the conversion to a scipy sparse matrix in order to be able to perform operations on it, or can I perform operations directly on the disk files (matrix multiplication etc ...) - i.e. without loading the file into memory (if not what's the point of using pytables?)?

Comment: Those errors are coming out of scipy.  Can you check on the ability of say just numpy to operate on `data`, `ir` or `jc`.  What does numpy have to say about the data (i.e. dtype, shape, etc.)?  Are the results what you expect? Do they correspond to what is expected in ``scipy.sparse.csc_matrix`` for that call signature?

Comment: Ah yes it seems all I had to do was:

`M = sparse.csc_matrix( (f2.root.M.data[...], f2.root.M.ir[...], f2.root.M.jc[...]) )`

Not sure about the second question yet? It seems like only elementwise operations are available on PyTables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I missed seeing this in your original post but I think your issue is in the design of PyTables, which provides an extra level of abstraction on top of the underlying data.

Consider the following:

```
>>> import tables
>>> import numpy as np

>>> h5_file = tables.openFile(fname)
>>> data = f2.root.M.data
```

At this point `data` is not a `numpy` array:

```
>>> type(data)
tables.array.Array

>>> isinstance(data, np.ndarray)
False
```

The `tables.array.Array` does immediately load the underlying array, or immediately expose array-like functionality.  This is what led to the error when you tried to use these types of objects to create a sparse array in `scipy`.

Instead the `data` object produced by `PyTables`  is intended to provide access to the data through additional commands (i.e. you did that by using fancy indexing `[...]`).  In this approach you can access parts of the data or all of it by doing `data[:]` or `data.read()`.  It is only at this point that the familiar `numpy` array is produced.

For more information on the `tables.array.Array` class see http://pytables.github.com/usersguide/libref.html#the-array-class or the `Getting actual data` section at http://www.pytables.org/moin/HowToUse for examples of accessing underlying data.

In comparison [pyh5](http://code.google.com/p/h5py/) produces much more array-like objects, although still not `numpy` arrays. Consider:

```
>>> import pyh5
>>> f1 = h5py.File(fname)
>>> data = f1['M']['data']
>>> type(data)
h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset
>>> isinstance(data, np.ndarray)
>>> False
```

However, you can immediately do `numpy` operations on `data` like you call to `scipy`, or more simple operations like `np.cos(data)` or `data + np.arange(len(data))`.  It also appears that `data` object has some familiar `numpy` like attributes (i.e. `shape`) and that the underlying data (a `numpy.ndarray`) is stored at `data.value`.  However, I'm not familiar with `pyh5` as I haven't used it myself, so I'm not sure what the limitations are in this regard.

In general it appears that `PyTables` and `pyh5` have different design goals and therefore should be used in different ways.  `pyh5` offers a more Numpy-like interface to HDF files, while `PyTables` offers a lot more complex database like operations.  See the discussion of the differences at the `pyh5`, `PyTables` docs and the Enthought mailing list:

- [http://code.google.com/p/h5py/wiki/FAQ#What's_the_difference_between_h5py_and_PyTables_?](http://code.google.com/p/h5py/wiki/FAQ#What%27s_the_difference_between_h5py_and_PyTables_?)
- http://www.pytables.org/moin/FAQ#HowdoesPyTablescomparewiththeh5pyproject.3F
- https://mail.enthought.com/pipermail/enthought-dev/2010-November/027506.html

Comment: Very useful answer thanks. Slowly getting to grips with this! I think PyTables will provide some useful functionality for our project, as scalability is important.